# Google Buzz API - How do I access my entire followers ? - Google Error

Tags: google-api, google-buzz

In Google buzz API, I need to get all my followers. Let's assume I have 1000 followers. But google buzz api allows me to get only 100 followers, there is no paging varaible in the API. And I am limited to set the `max-results` to 100. If I put `max-results` to 1000, google automatically reduce it to 100. How can i get all my followers in API

https://www.googleapis.com/buzz/v1/people/@me/@groups/@following?alt=json

Thanks

Sreeraj

Answer (score 1):

According to http://code.google.com/apis/buzz/v1/using_rest.html#query-params there is a `c` parameter in addition to `max-results`.
It is defined as

> An opaque continuation token that allows paginating through a large collection of entries.

You receive the 'c' value on the fist request, and passing it in to subsequent requests will give them the proper offset.

Comment: This is onbly in the case of activities. It willl not reflect in the people feed :(

Comment: it says 'All operations that return resource collections', not 'All operations that return activity resources' so it seems that this should work for that.